# Need help on PHP file issue

Tags: php

We are recently facing this problem out of sudden, wondering if there are any possibility why this problem happen.

Here's the error:

> Warning: require_once(system/core/System.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 32
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'system/core/System.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 32

Comment: i think the error message is clear

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it answers itself.

Answer (score 0):

edit your "php.ini" file and change the value of "open_basedir" which allows the php to access this path. Then make sure your "include_path" points to where you want it to point (as suggested by people in the comments).